# Continue when element is not found in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
up_key.click()
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath))
if item.text == 'awesome text':
    driver.quit()
```

The `up_key.click()` clicks on the up key image on the site, it sometimes creates a new element in AJAX which is displayed in the webpage. That new element I try to get with:
 
`item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath))`

But like I said it creates sometimes a new element but not always, and the text of that element is also not always `awesome text`.

So if the `up_key.click()` would clicked again, then AJAX would either change the text of the element, or keep the same text, or remove the element. This is everytime random when `up_key.click()` clicks.

I want the script to continue doing `up_key.click()`, untill it finds `awesome text` then it should stop.

something like:

```
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath))
while item.text != 'awesome text':
    up_key.click()
    item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you have to surround the text with a try block

```
while True:
    try:
        up_key.click()
        item = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath))
        if item.text != 'awesome text':
            continue
        driver.close()
    except:
        print "Not found"
```

Comment: How can this code be improved? Asking because of the downvote